# How to create Irish flag using just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created the Indian flag using HTML and CSS(except the *Ashok Chakra*). Now I want to create the Irish flag which is just vertical tricolor rather than horizontal tricolor like in case of the Indian flag. So how do I achieve it? I have created these following codes.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

.top {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
}

.mid {
  background-color: white;
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
}

.botm {
  background-color: green;
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="india.css">
  <title>Flag</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="botm"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lot of ways to create 3 columns

Comment: Your real question is _how to place divs on the same row?_ Try searching for that and you will find millions of articles.

Answer (score 4):

A single div with a `linear-gradient` or a double inset `box-shadow` as in the examples below could be enough

---

**linear-gradient**

```css
.irishflag { 
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #169B62 33.33%, #fff 0, #fff 66.66%, #FF883E 0);
        width: 270px;
        height: 135px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="irishflag"></div>
```

---

**box-shadow**

```css
.irishflag { 
    box-shadow: 90px 0 #169B62 inset, -90px 0 #FF883E inset;
    width: 270px;
    height: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="irishflag"></div>
```

Colours and proprtion are taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ireland)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a flag container with `display:flex`; and **reverse order**. Like this:

```css
body{
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-left:40%;    
  margin-right:40%;
}

.top{
  background-color:orange;
  width:320px;
  height:80px;
}

.mid{
  background-color:white;
  width:320px;
  height:80px;
}

.botm{
  background-color:green;
  width:320px;
  height:80px;
}

.flag{
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flag">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="botm"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: with flex, you can use pseudos ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWwwbxe

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to align your 'colors' in a row like this:

```css
body{
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-left:40%;    
    margin-right:40%;
    display: flex     /* <-- Make children aligned in a row */
}

.right{
    background-color:orange;
    width:320px;
    height:80px;
}

.mid{
    background-color:white;
    width:320px;
    height:80px;
}

.left{
    background-color:green;
    width:320px;
    height:80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way by giving the parent `div` a display value of `flex`:

```
display: flex;
```

And then all of its direct children a `flex` value, indicating that the width of each should approximate one third of the width of the parent:

```
flex: 1 1 33%;
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.flag {
  display: flex;
  width: 291px;
  height: 180px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.third {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}

.ireland .left {
  background-color: green;
}

.ireland .center {
  background-color: white;
}

.ireland .right {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag ireland">
  <div class="left third"></div>
  <div class="center third"></div>
  <div class="right third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: with flex, you can use pseudos ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWwwbxe

Answer (score -1):

FLOAT WAY:

```
 .top {
     background-color:
         orange;
     width: 120px;
     height: 320px;
     float: left;
 }

 .mid {
     background-color:
         white;
     width: 120px;
     height: 320px;
     float: left;
 }

 .botm {
     background-color:
         green;
     width: 120px;
     height: 320px;
     float: left;
 }

 .flag {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="flag">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="botm"></div>
  </div>
```